# Detecting IRC colors within a String 

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, irc

How can I go about detecting [IRC color codes](http://www.mirc.com/colors.html) within a String?

Here's what I've tried:

```
int length = message.length();
ArrayList<Object> buffer = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  char ch = message.charAt(i);
  if (Character.isDefined(ch) && !Character.isLetter(ch)) {
    Methods.log("val " + (int) ch);//Attempt logging the irc color value
  } else {
    buffer.add(ch);
  }
}
```

However this failed. I'm writing an IRC client for my grade 11 programming class and I figured colors would be a cool feature to add.

Comment: Matt, you need to provide a little bit more info. The best way to do this would be to expand the code you have provided to include the name of the method, the parameters it accepts and the data that is returned by the method. That will provide a better definition of what you want to achieve. Also you should describe the failure in terms of the errors you received, what your expectations were how they were not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IRC colors are ["specified" by mIRC](http://www.mirc.com/colors.html) -- it's complicated, and not all clients interpret the specification the same way -- but you're looking for the `^C` "control character" (`0x03`) followed by digits that describe which specific foreground and background colors to use.

Once you've found them in the stream of text you'll need to figure out how to change the text color on your text widgets *and* remember to set the text back to normal before the next message is output.

Comment: IRC color codes are, unfortunately, not ANSI color codes. They're an annoyingly ambiguous custom thing created by Khaled for mIRC: http://www.mirc.com/colors.html

Comment: @duskwuff: oh, man, you're right. I'd completely forgotten. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

fixed

```
        int length = message.length();
        LinkedList<Object> buffer = new LinkedList<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char ch = message.charAt(i);
            if ((byte) ch == 3) {
                String color = "";
                i++;
                while (i < length) {//loop
                    char d = message.charAt(i);
                    if ((d >= '0') && (d <= '9')) {
                        if (color.length() == 2) {
                            i--;
                            break;//break b4 stackoverflow!!!
                        }
                        color += d;
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        i--;
                        break;//break b4 stackoverflow!!!
                    }
                }
                for (IRCModifier m : IRCModifier.values()) {
                    if (m.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(color)
                            || m.getCode().replace("0", "")
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(color)) {
                        buffer.add(m.getEffect());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                buffer.add(ch);
            }
        }
```